# Use a text string as the binding parameter in Xamarin Value Convertor

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I use IValueConverters a lot in my Xamarin projects. I would like to use any arbitrary string of text as the binding parameter, rather than have to bind to a property on my View or ViewModel. Often I find myself having to create what I see as arbitrary / superfluous properties on my view model just to support the functionality I want, which clutters my code. The use case for this is using a converter to get a translated string from a custom XML file. (In my project I cannot use the standard resx file i18n approach - I need to traverse an XML file to find the string I need).

I would like to do this in Xaml:

```
<Label Text="{Binding 'my-awesome-string-of-text',
 Converter={StaticResource ConvertMyStringToSomethingElseConvertor}}"/>
```

and to have the string 'my-awesome-string-of-text' flow through to the object parameter of the IValueConvertor (ConvertMyStringToSomethingElseConvertor in this example).

But I find myself having to do this instead

```
<Label Text="{Binding MyUneccessaryStringProperty,
 Converter={StaticResource ConvertMyStringToSomethingElseConvertor}}"/>
```

and on my view model (mvvm light syntax) having to maintain the property

```
private string _myUneccessaryStringProperty 
public string MyUneccessaryStringProperty 
        {
            get => _myUneccessaryStringProperty ;
            set => SetProperty(ref _myUneccessaryStringProperty , value);
        }
```

Can what I want be done? For a page with a lot of different translatable strings the ViewModel quickly becomes cluttered.

Comment: It might be possible to use the [x:Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions#the-xstatic-markup-extension) markup extension to get the functionality.

Comment: @Andrew I've been playing around with that but can't get anything to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT! This can be done with an IMarkupExtension!

It has been implemented in the [Xamarin Commmunity toolkit](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit) for getting translated strings from RESX files in the [TranslateExtension](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/XamarinCommunityToolkit/Extensions/TranslateExtension.shared.cs). I have adapted their approach to pull from my custom translations XML file and bind to that, something like this:

````
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Text))]
    public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string StringFormat { get; set; }
        object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => ProvideValue(serviceProvider);

        public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
#if !NETSTANDARD1_0

                var t = MyCustomTranslationsHolder.Get(Text);
                var binding = new Binding
                {
                    Mode = BindingMode.OneTime,
                    Path = $"text",
                    Source = new {text = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t) ? t : Text},
                    StringFormat = StringFormat
                };
                return binding;
            
#else
            throw new NotSupportedException("Translate XAML MarkupExtension is not supported on .NET Standard 1.0");
#endif
        }
    }
    ```
````

Then in the xaml for example the Text property of a label

```
    Text="{converters:Translate 'The.Particular.Resource.Key'}"
```

The string displayed will be either the translation if it was successful, or the resource string if not, for debugging.

## Original answer, for posterity

I found an acceptable answer, relating to Andrew's suggestion in the comments.

Basically I create a static class called translations and set static properties to the value of the translations in the way my app gets them.

```
namespace MyApp.Utilities
{

    private static string _myAwesomeString;

    public static string MyAwesomeString

    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_myAwesomeString))
            {
                MyAwesomeString= GetTranslation("MyAwesomeResource");
            }
            return _myAwesomeString;
        }
        private set => _myAwesomeString = value;
    }
}
```

And then reference in xaml like so:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static utils:Translations.MyAwesomeString}"></Label>
```

Using the get/set accessors ensure that the GetTranslation call will only run once, effectively giving me efficient in memory dictionary-like access to resources that are used across multiple screens.

I still need to actually have the properties in a class, which is not ideal - but at least this way they are all in one place and not cluttering the viewmodels. If anyone knows a solution where I don't need to keep actual properties please let me know!

Comment: Actually that is how it is done in Plugin.Multilingual, if you read my answer everything points to this...

Comment: That's cool thanks Ivan. Glad I came up with something that is similar to a respected plugin that gives me confidence it is a good solution. I think my answer will get folks to a solution easier than having to peruse the source code of a plugin so I won't make yours the accepted answer - but have an upvote!

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction. Did you confirm that this works as intended? The part that worries me is setting the public `MyAwesomeString` inside the if then returning the private `_myAwesomeString`. While it "should" work because the private setter "should" be called before the return in the getter, it seems it would make more sense to set `_myAwesomeString = GetTranslation()` inside the if. I could be wrong though, just make sure to thoroughly test it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew - I have removed the setter completely and am just setting the private variable directly as you suggest - I've got it down to one line now too with a helper method.

```public static string MyAwesomeString => GetTranslation(ref _undetected, "MyAwesomeResource");``

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but not exactly like that. You need to have your namespace prefix that would eventually do the similar thing that the converter does. Look at the Plugin.Multilingual on github. Of course there is no binding. Binding is meant for binding, not running the arbitrary code in the arbitrary way.

Comment: Thanks Ivan. The plugin looks great, but because I inherited the codebase I have to support a custom XML resource file structure for my translatable strings rather than a standard resx so I don't think it will work here. Maybe I can fork it or get some inspiration to work with my custom file.

Comment: @AdamDiament, yes my answer related to that, you need to do something similar to what they do, and you can see their code and start from there.